# Script Task on SQL Server works after rebuilt or migration

Tags: c#, deployment, ssis, package, ssms

Having developed software that is capable to generate automated DTSX packages for SQL Server using EzAPI, while included a script task with Web Client, strange things started happening.

The script task is referring to a DLL from GAC which using reflection calls an API to do things.

Here are the strange things:

Once I export the package for SQL Server 2012, if I deploy it on SQL Server 2012 it works but doesn’t communicate with the remote server.
On the other hand, the same package for SQL Server 2012, if I deploy it to a newer version of SQL Server it works and communicates with a remote server.

Once I export the package for SQL Server 2014, if I deploy it on SQL Server 2014 it works but doesn’t communicate with the remote server.
On the other hand, the same package for SQL Server 2014, if I deploy it to a newer version of SQL Server it works and communicates with a remote server.

Once I export the package for SQL Server 2016, if I deploy it on SQL Server 2016 it works but doesn’t communicate with the remote server.
On the other hand, the same package for SQL Server 2016, if I deploy it to a newer version of SQL Server it works and communicates with a remote server.

Also, seems that if I open the package with DataTools or Visual Studio it works but doesn’t communicate with the remote server.
On the other hand, if I rebuilt the Script Task then it works and communicates with the remote server.

I have concluded that migration forces the script task to rebuild the code and that’s the reason for working while deploying in higher versions.

But no idea why the code is not working without being migrated or rebuild. Make a note that the same 2014 package is not working on 2014 but works on 2016. Also 2012 package is not working in 2012 but the same package works in 2014. So the issue is not the version of SQL, neither any code issue.

In addition, we made a syntax error on purpose inside the script task while developing though VSTA, the script task was built successfully and we deployed the package on SQL Server 2012. The package was reported successful execution via SSIDB without doing enything. On the other hand, we deployed the same package for SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2014 and the SSMS reported that the package could not build the script task.

Now seems that the script task is bypassed while deployed in the same version of SQL Server and always returns success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after some deep dive into the problem, I figured out the problem, normally I would delete my question but anyhow this is revealing what is happening inside Microsoft Tools and therefore may be helpful.

Normally the code should follow specific steps to create a script task and embedded inside the Package is the following.

```
// 1. Create a script task
var th = (TaskHost)exec;
th.Name = "Script Task";
th.Description = "This is a Script Task";
var task = (ScriptTask)th.InnerObject;

// 2. Set the script language - "CSharp" or "VisualBasic"
task.ScriptLanguage = VSTAScriptLanguages.GetDisplayName("CSharp");

// 3. Set any variables used by the script
//task.ReadWriteVariables = "User::Var1, User::Var2";

// 4. Create a new project from the template located in the default path
task.ScriptingEngine.VstaHelper.LoadNewProject(task.ProjectTemplatePath, null, "MyScriptProject");

// 5. Initialize the designer project, add a new code file, and build
//task.ScriptingEngine.VstaHelper.Initalize("", true);
//task.ScriptingEngine.VstaHelper.AddFileToProject("XX.cs", "FileContents");
//task.ScriptingEngine.VstaHelper.Build("");

// 6. Persist the VSTA project + binary to the task
if (!task.ScriptingEngine.SaveProjectToStorage())
{
    throw new Exception("Save failed");
}

// 7. Use the following code to replace the ScriptMain contents
var contents = File.ReadAllText("path to file");
var scriptFile =
    task.ScriptStorage.ScriptFiles["ScriptMain.cs"] =
    new VSTAScriptProjectStorage.VSTAScriptFile(VSTAScriptProjectStorage.Encoding.UTF8, contents);

// 8. Reload the script project, build and save
task.ScriptingEngine.LoadProjectFromStorage();
task.ScriptingEngine.VstaHelper.Build("");

// 9. Persist the VSTA project + binary to the task
if (!task.ScriptingEngine.SaveProjectToStorage())
{
    throw new Exception("Save failed");
}
```

Seems very strange forward right?

In case, you forgot the last set of code lines (.9), what will happen?

```
// 9. Persist the VSTA project + binary to the task
if (!task.ScriptingEngine.SaveProjectToStorage())
{
    throw new Exception("Save failed");
}
```

Then the magic starts happening, the package definition will contain your actual code but the binary will still be an image of the old Intiatilize script which always returns success.

In that case, if you deploy the package to the same version of SQL Server, SQL Server will not do a build of your code, because already have one, which is wrong. On the other hand, if you deploy on a higher version of SQL Server, the package definition is changing and therefore, it builds your actual script, and then it's working.

Same case for DataTools / VisualStudio, if you open the package with DataTools / VisualStudio and execute it, it will execute the build inside the definition which is an image of the original initialization script. On the other hand, if you open the script, the script will be rebuild based on the code and it will work in the next execution.